# Creating daemon process in UNIX enviroment

Tags: c, linux, fork, systems-programming

I have picked the following example from APUE :

```
void daemonize(const char* cmd)
{
        int i,fd0,fd1,fd2;
        pid_t pid;
        struct rlimit r1;
        struct sigaction sa;

        //clear all file masks
        umask(0);

        //get max number of file descriptors
        if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,&r1) < 0)
        {
                perror("error getting file descriptor size");
                return;
        }

        //become a session leader
        if((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
                perror("error forking");
                return;
        }
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
                setsid();
        }
        else
        {
                exit(0); //parent exits
        }

        sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_flags = 0;
        if(sigaction(SIGHUP,&sa,NULL) < 0)
        {
                return;
        }

        if((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
                return;
        }
        else if(pid != 0)
        {
                exit(0); //parent
        }

        //child continues

        syslog(LOG_ERR,"chile continuing with pid : %d",getpid());
        //change the working directory
        if(chdir("/") < 0)
        {
                return;
        }

        if(r1.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
                r1.rlim_max = 1024;
        for(i=0;i<r1.rlim_max;i++)
                close(i);

        //attach the file descriptors to /dev/null
        fd0 = open("/dev/null",O_RDWR);
        fd1 = dup(0);
        fd2 = dup(0);

        //initialize the log file
        openlog(cmd, LOG_CONS,LOG_DAEMON);
        if(fd0!=0 || fd1!=1 || fd2!=2)
        {
                syslog(LOG_ERR,"unexpected file descriptors %d %d %d\n",fd0,fd1,fd2);
                exit(1);
        }
}


int main()
{
        daemonize("date");
        pause();    //how is this working???
}
```

What I don't understand is how the `pause()` from the main function is working? What I was expecting is that since we have done `exit(0)` for the parent process in `daemonize()`, it should have exited and resulted in the normal termination of the main() process. It should have never returned to the `main()` and the call to `pause()` should not even happen. Why it did not terminate and why the `pause()` got called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code forks twice, producing a parent, a child, and a grandchild. The first two each `exit(0)`; the last returns from `daemonize`.

Comment: @aah... I missed that. Thanks. In fact, for a second i forgot that fact that the grandchild will still be executing the code as the gradparent (except few if-checks based on pid).

Comment: One more question please, why we have called second `fork()` here when we had already done `setsid()` and started a new session. Is there a problem in continuing as a session and group leader after `setsid()`?

Comment: @insane: That's explained in the note right at the top of page 426: it prevents the daemon from acquiring a controlling terminal even if it happens to open a terminal device.